# Update Apple Subscription state for IAP to our server

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, in-app-purchase

We have implemented server-side receipt validation for all types of subscriptions. Now the point is when we upgrade the plan from iPhone settings we receive **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS** notification type and on cancel subscription, we also receive **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS**. How can we know which status is for what?

Our logic on the server-side is if we receive **INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL** or **DID_RENEW** means the plan has upgraded and if we receive **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS** than the plan is canceled or expired.

And also have a couple of questions:

1. we want to know If we canceled the plan from the settings, Did Apple
   will send a notification immediately or when the plan expires?
2. We we downgrade plan will Apple send downgrade server to server
   notification immediately or when the current plan expires bcoz we
   don't want to know new downgrade plan to the user till the current
   plan expires?

We have used technology: NodeJS and React Native

Answer (score 2):

The notifications are sometimes a bit confusing and I wouldn't rule out the possibility that they might be wrong. But corresponding to the 2020 WWDC video [What’s new with in-app purchase](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10661/) (see 15min 42seconds) you should receive and **INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL** for the upgrade plus a **CANCEL** for the previous lower-tier subscription.

The online [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type) for the notification types, states in "Handle Use Cases for Notification Events" that you should receive the following notifications for an upgrade: **CANCEL**, **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS**, **INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL**.

That you receive a **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS** notification for the "cancel" is correct, since no one, except the Apple support, can cancel a subscription. What you really do in the *Manage Subscriptions* dialog is deactivating the auto-renewal and therefore only changing the renewal status.

About your other questions:

1. Apple will immediately send the **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS**, when a user deactivated ("canceled") the auto-renewal of his subscription.
2. When a user downgrades, Apple will send immediately a **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF** notification. Keep in mind that the downgrade will only happen on the next auto-renew. Until then the user is eligible to access the content from the higher plan.

Comment: If I am not wrong On Downgrade the plan Apple sends DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF right? @paul-schröder

Comment: Also When a downgrade event-triggered we are not updating the state to downgrade plan because the new plan will be in effect after the current plan expires. So once that current plan expires will Apple sends any notification? If yes then which type of notification?

Comment: You are completely right, thank you for pointing that out. I corrected my answer with the right notification type.

Comment: Yes, the user keeps this access level until the subscription renews. You will receive a **DID_RENEW** when the new plan starts

Comment: Thanks @paul-schröder

Comment: Also Once the user cancels the subscription we receive **DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS**  but the actual plan is going to expire after 3 days. So will Apple sends any notification after 3 days? If yes then which type of notification?

Comment: The user can't cancel. He only deactivates the auto-renewal and therefore his subscription is valid until its expiration date. When this is due, you won't receive a separate notification

Comment: So in this scenario, how to maintain state in DB if the user deactivates the auto-renewal and his subscription is valid until its expiration date and after expired subscription, the user should be notified that plan is expired or update DB state.

Comment: This is hard to tell without knowing our database structure and it depends on how and when you want to react or inform a user about potential "problems" (losing access). Normally, your app ask your server if the user is eligible to access a specific content and the server then will check if the user has an active subscription (purchaseDate < currentDate && currentDate < expirationDate && cancelationDate == nil).

Comment: For the case that the currentDate is greater than the expirationDate, I would check if the user has deactivated auto-renewal. If this is the case, I would let the server return false. Otherwise, I would trigger the verifyEndpoint from Apple with the latest receipt of the user and check if this returns a renewed receipt. If this also fails, I would return true while the current date is before *grace_period_expires_date* and otherwise false.

Comment: You can also check for billing issues and inform the user about that, but this should be already handled by your server when you received a **DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW** notification.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to implement all scenarios.

Comment: Apple sends DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF notification when I upgrade my plan. Is this because my Trial period is true? @paul-schröder